# linq how to pull an int col and compare with 0

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq..
this is what i am trying to do

```
   bool bPresent = (from r in dsInternalInformation.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                       select r.Field<int>("QstnCount")) > 0;
```

I want to pull the value of QstnCount and compare it with zero and return true or false.

Basically i want to convert the below statement into linq

> int.Parse(dsInternalInformation.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QstnCount"].ToString()) > 0

Pls help

Comment: Whats you Linq data source. A list, sql, entity framework?

Comment: Do you want to know if there is at least one row with QstnCount > 0, or whether QstnCount > 0 in a specific row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"select" is what you get out of the LINQ query. Use "where" to filter.

Guessing that dsInternalInformation is a DataSet and that you want you want to find out if any row has a QstnCount > 0:

```
bool bPresent = (from DataRow r in dsInternalInformation.Tables[0].Rows
                 where (int)r["QstnCount"] > 0 select r).Any();
```

Comment: @Karan - updated the example, added a "select" that is required in this form of linq statement, changed the query slightly.

Comment: Table contains only one row.. we dont need datarow r.

Comment: @Karan - the "from" syntax **requires** a "select" clause. This query just checks whether there *is* a row (with count > 0).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
bool bPresent = (from r in dsInternalInformation.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    select r.Field<int>("QstnCount")).ToList().FirstOrDefault() > 0;
```

The `select r.Field<int>("QstnCount")` part will cause collection of all `QstnCount` values to be returned, so you need to make it a generic List then take the first, if exists - now you got ordinary integer you can compare with 0.

Answer (score 0):

No need for LINQ whatsoever, no need for int.Parse either. So the improvement is to remove the ToString and the Parse. If QstnCount is already of type int, just cast it as such or use the Field extension method.

```
dsInternalInformation.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<int>("QstnCount") > 0
```

Or:

```
((int)dsInternalInformation.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QstnCount"]) > 0
```

Or:

```
dsInternalInformation.Tables.First().Rows.First().Field<int>("QstnCount") > 0
```

It looks like you're not interested in a set, only in the QstnCount value of the first (and probably only) row in the first (and probably only) table. Then there is no need for LINQ, as linq is used to query over lists and trees. If you just want to query a single object, then don't use it to complicate things further.